# Oracle Java Tree Tutorial: Where and how to implement the tutorial code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtree

I am now trying to learn java tree in java oracle tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) at creating a tree part. I have difficulties to implement the code inside my netbean jframe. where should i put the code. currently i put the code inside my public class jframe as shown below but return error.

[image]

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: initComponents(); // cannot find symbol

Comment: private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) { //illegal start of expression

Comment: well what i do is i copy paste the tutorial code to my netbean jframe public jframe. defining initComponent() might solve the issue but how do we define it? initcomponent() was auto created when i create new jframe class from netbean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) { //illegal start of expression`

Whoa, from the looks of your image, the method `createNodes` is inside the constructor, Hence `//illegal start of expression`. You'll want to take that out of the constructor and put it on the class level.

**Side Note**

- In Netbeans, make use of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to properly indent your code. You may notice errors you wouldn't see otherwise, like maybe *this* one :)
- Providing us with actual text code is much more effective than providing a screen shot of your code.

Comment: i have taken out the code from constructor, but still blur on how to implement the code with netbean. even when i paste it to class other error occur. maybe the code was incomplete after all. you have any idea how to run the code mr @peeskillet.

here the link, see at "creating a tree section" 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html. 
i am sure this is suppose to be a simple thing to do for other otherwise it will not be called tutorial ;)

Comment: Are you just talking about the `TreeDemo`?

Comment: In every tutorial, you will see a link to the complete java source code. What you are trying to do is add the snippet from the totorial. If you see the link [TreeDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TreeDemoProject/src/components/TreeDemo.java) it will take you to the complete source code, and you can run _that_

Comment: yes, it kind a newbie right, hope you dont mind help me out. :)

Comment: owh, snap that why the code wont run does't it. thanks appreaciate your help

Comment: Whenever you see a .java link in the tutorial, it will link to the source code of the current tutorial. Also you can see _all_ source code for _all_ tutorials in the [example index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TreeDemo) link